# Dart: How to use the dot notation, uncaught TypeError Problem

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code in dart, which decodes a string into a JSON object.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main(){
  var stringValue = "{\"last_supported\": \"2.00\", \"current\": \"2.00\"}";
  var newValue = json.decode(stringValue);

  print(newValue["last_supported"]);
}
```

The above code works fine, but when I change print statement to:
`print(newValue.last_supported);`
It gives me the following exception:
`Uncaught TypeError: C.C_JsonCodec.decode$1(...).get$last_supported is not a function`

Is it possible to use dot annotation to access properties, and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you come from a java-script background.

in dart object keys cannot be accessed through the `.` dot notation.
rather they are accessed like arrays with `['key_name']`.

so that's why this line doesn't work

```dart
print(newValue.last_supported)
```

and this one does

```dart
print(newValue["last_supported"]);
```

dot notation in dart only works on class instances, not Map (similar to JavaScript objects).
look at the following :

```dart
class User {
   final String name;
   final int age;
   // other props;

   User(this.name, this.age);
}
```

Now when you create a new user object you can access its public attributes with the dot notation

```dart
final user = new User("john doe", 20); // the new keyword is optional since Dart v2

// this works
print(user.name);
print(user.age);

// this doesn't work because user is an instance of User class and not a Map.
print(user['name]);
print(user['age]);
```

For more about the `new` keyword you can read the v2 release notes [here](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6#da82).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, as a javascript dev, I definitely was confused by this.